# using a discord bot to type on multiple pc's

Tags: discord-buttons

I want to make a script that links with a discord bot so that when you click a web hook button it types "/vp" on any devices with the script installed. me and my friends want to use this to help each other when afk on a Minecraft server. my main issue is figuring out how to make the script run on multiple devices, I cant find a good way of doing it.

I have looked around and cannot find a way to run the script on other devices at the same time